# How do I find the path to existing text resource file in bundle?

Tags: swift, macos, file-io, resources, bundle

I am trying to load an existing text file that is stored as a resource that is bundled inside my Xcode project.  I am unable to set a variable to the path to this file and therefore cannot get to the read stage.

1. I create a project: new->MacOS->Command Line Tool->called “Pants”
2. In the Project Navigator, click on the yellow folder called Pants. File->New file…MacOS->Resource->Rich Text File. I name this “Nick”. Group is Pants, Targets is ticked as Pants.
3. I type “Hello wonderful world” into this file. File->Close “Nick.rtf”
4. In Project Navigator, under yellow folder Pants, I can see Nick.rtf
5. In Project Navigator, click top level blue icon, Pants. Select Build Phases->+, New Copy Bundle Resource Phase. I drag the Nick.rtf file from the Project Navigator into the “Add resource files here”. [I've noticed that sometimes the file has already been put here]
6. In main.swift, I add my code given below.  This is modified from: [Read and write a String from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file)

   ```
   import Foundation

   print("Hello, World!")

       if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Nick" , ofType: nil) {
               print("will read")
       } else {
           print("Failed to load file from bundle")
           }
   ```

When this is run, Product->Run, my file is not found:

> > Hello, World! Failed to load file from bundle Program ended with exit code: 0

a. I have tried changing Type “rtf”. I have tried Nil.  If use the full project path in Mac Finder, I can see the file “Nick.rtf” stored in Documents->SwiftCode->Pants->Pants

b. I have tried variations of names, file types, locations, etc. I have tried Files->Add files to “Pants”…

c. If I drag the Nick.rtf from the Project Navigator into my source file, it gives the path as:

> /Users/XXX/Documents/SwiftCode/Pants/Pants/Nick.rtf

I still appear unable to determine the path of my resource in the bundle inside my project using Swift code, so that I can then (finally) load the text file. I assume the file is not actually inside the resource bundle - I cannot determine how to get it there?

Comment: The problem is that "Command-line Tool" targets don't really have a bundle.

Comment: Also [Getting path for resource in command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38422467)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I should have realised that the Command-Line tool does not have a bundle.  Rather obvious now you say it! It is a shame that the IDE does not help you a little more - ah well, back to my days of 8-bit opcodes...